# Robot Framework/Selenium: Xpath to get only keys count

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

From the Below html page I am trying to write below keywords but i am having tough time to get exact count of keys using generic xpath.

html is:

```
<table class="tabletext">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large">Collector Information</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="tabletext">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:medium" colspan="2" align="left">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; " width="700px">General Application Statistics</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Local Radios</td>
<td align="left">AA.5E.AZ.21.13.04[Z0136FBZ]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">MAC Address</td>
<td align="left">91-99-99-0C-66-B2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Version</td>
<td align="left">14.48.24.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:medium" colspan="2" align="left">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; " width="700px">Legacy Configuration</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Default Geo Code</td>
<td align="left">AF.ZA.QE.23.23.1F</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

These are my keywords .. I am able to get matching xpath in "Obtain Collector Information Sections" Keyword. but i am failing to get right xpath to get no of keys in "Obtain Values From Collector Information Sections"

```
Obtain Collector Information Sections
    [Documentation]
    ${No_Of_Sections} =  get matching xpath count  //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@style='color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; ']]
    @{list} =   Create List
    : FOR   ${Count}  IN Range 1 ${No_Of_Sections}
    \  ${Section_Header_Name} = Get Value   //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@style='color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; ']][${Count}]
    \  ${Information_Section_${Count}} =  Obtain Values From Collector Information Sections   ${Section_Header_Name}
    \  log dictionary   ${Information_Section_${Count}}
    \  Append To List   ${list}  ${Information_Section_${Count}}


Obtain Values From Collector Information Sections
    [Documentation]
    [Arguments]  ${Section_Header_Name}
    ${Information_Section} =  Create Dictionary
    ${No_Of_Key_Value} =  get matching xpath count  //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td
    : FOR  ${Count}   IN Range 1 ${No_Of_Key_Value}
    \  ${Key} =  Get Value   //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[${Count}]/td[1]
    \  ${Value} =  Get Value   //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[${Count}]/td[2]
    \  set to dictionary   ${Information_Section}    ${Key}   ${Value}
    [Return]  ${Information_Section}
```

I am failing to get the accurate count at this line. My intention to get only list of keys (Not any values) to add it to Dictionary.

```
${No_Of_Key_Value} =  get matching xpath count  //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td
```

Above one is returning key& value pair set. But i need only count of keys from "General Application Statistics" section to iterate through for loop.

Could you please help me here! Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *keys* and *values* and what is the exact desired output?

Comment: html page got 2 sections, each section got some fields like this "Local Radios""AA.5E.AZ.21.13.04[Z0136FBZ]"&"MAC Address""91-99-99-0C-66-B2". From this e.g. Local value& MAC Address are Key's and AA.5E.AZ.21.13.04[Z0136FBZ]&91-99-99-0C-66-B2 are their Values. I am taking them into Dictionary. So when i want to retrive/print i will pass jus key and respective value get prints..